# App crash when deleting collection view cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

I have enabled multiselect of collection view.(Xcode 7,iOS 9)

```
 NSArray *paths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];

// data source
 for (NSIndexPath *path in paths) {
   [datasourceArray removeObjectAtIndex:path.item];
  }

// delete 
 [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:paths];
```

I have 9 items . it crashes with this message:

> reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:]: index 8 beyond bounds [0 .. 7]'

But if you only delete the last one (8), it works fine.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what happens to an array when you delete an element - all the elements above shuffle down 1, so element 8 is now element 7, element 7 is now element 6 and so on.  So when you delete element 6, there is no longer an element 9, so you get an out of bounds exception.

Rather than calling `removeObjectAtIndex` in a loop, you can use the `removeObjectsAtIndexes:` method -

```
NSArray *paths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];

NSMutableIndexSet removeIndexes=[NSMutableIndexSet new];

for (NSIndexPath *path in paths) {
    [removeIndexes addIndex:path.item];
}

// delete 
[datasourceArray removeObjectAtIndexes:removeIndexes];
[self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:paths];
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I want to undo deletion,   use `[self.collectionview reloadData]; But the old pictures in cell didn't update ,an new one shows, so there are two pictures in one cell.How can I fix it?

Comment: You should ask another question and show your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` but it sounds like you are adding an imagview when a cell is reused rather than using the one that is already there.